# how to estimate parameters of negative binomial distribution in R using maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a dataframe like that:

```
                             word freq1 freq2 freq3 freq4 freq5 freq6 
                          1   a    141   97    103   158   71    101
                          2   b    84    41    51    42    19    22
                          3   c    15    24    33    87    102   59
                          4   d    9     33    41    19    93    75
                          5   e    1     0     4     15    21    16
                          6   f    91    31    42    16    75    9
```

I want to calculate parameters (r,p) of Negative Binomial Distribution using maximum likelihood estimation in R for each word in my dataframe.

For example `word_a <- c(141,97,103,158,71,101)`
How can I use mle method to estimate parameters of distribution for this vector "word_a"?

Comment: See `?MASS::glm.nb`

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you want to do. Is this something per word? What do you imply by assigning the vector of numeric to the word?

Comment: I have a book with 6 chapters. this numbers are numbers of word occurrences in each chapter. Assuming that frequencies of words have NBD

Comment: This link will solve your problem [Binomial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/)